x64dbg string references can not find
i am trying to register a software with x64dbg, but my experience is not enaugh for do this. Anyone can help me ? i am ready to pay price. Problem is can not find string references in x64dbg.i already tryed several methods
intermoduler calls, printf, messageboxa, sendmesage, etc, All other methods which i was know
+905326343906 or kagakadir@hotmail.com
